# Get following blogs comments

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a blog site in SharePoint 2013. In this site there are two lists: "posts " and "Comments".

Now I'm getting post list items using sp query. Whenever a user enters the comments in the post it will update the comments list.

Whenever a user enters the comments latest modified, it will not update the post list but comments list only getting update. I need to get recently modified items from the post list based on the comments updated.

Comment: is your solution based on event receivers?